# Android 3.1, trouble displaying two counters side by side

Tags: android-3.1-honeycomb

Im new to programming and I am having a hard time trying to figure this one out.  I'm trying to create two visible separate counters on each side of the tablet.  One is the the left of the tablet, the other on the right of the tablet.  When i click the left button it updates the count on the left(e.g., 1+1+1 etc) but when I click on the right counter, it adds an additional value to sum up on the left counter.  (e.g., click on right (adds 1, then when i click on the left counter it acts such as add 2, instead of 1.)

here is what my code looks like so far

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;



public class swim2 extends Activity {

// References to UI views
EditText txtCount;
EditText txtCount2;
Button PUp;
Button NUp;


static int Count = 0;    // Initial count
static int Count2 = 0;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main3);
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub




        Button previous = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);
        previous.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                 Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), swim1.class);
                    startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
            }

        }); 
     // Retrieve references to UI views by their id in XML layout
        NUp = (Button)findViewById(R.id.incremintationbutton2);    
        txtCount2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.ni); 
        txtCount2.setText(String.valueOf(Count2)); //Set initial value


        NUp = (Button)findViewById(R.id.incremintationbutton2);
        // Process the button on-click event
        NUp.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

           public void onClick(View Button) {
               Count++;
               txtCount2.setText(String.valueOf(Count2));
           }
        });
        PUp = (Button)findViewById(R.id.incremintationbutton1);
        txtCount = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.pi);
        txtCount.setText(String.valueOf(Count));  // Set initial value

        PUp = (Button)findViewById(R.id.incremintationbutton1);
        PUp.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
               public void onClick(View Button) {
                  Count++;
                  txtCount.setText(String.valueOf(Count));
               }
            });

}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it, had to change one of the count++, to count2++.. took me a while but i figured it out after a cup of coffee.